# Find $a$ and $b$ if $0 < x < 5$ then $a < x + 2 < b$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I am trying to solve this simple equation but I am not able to figure out how to do it. Can somebody give me a hand?

> If $0 < x < 5$ then $a < x + 2 < b$.

Comment: It is not an equation. (It does not have an equal sign.)

Answer (score 0):

We have:
$$0 < x < 5$$
Now, we want to get to $x+2$. Thus, add all sides of the inequality by $2$:
$$2 < x+2 < 7$$
We now find that $a=2$ and $b=7$.

Comment: We only have $a\geq 2$ and $b\leq 7$. (Obviously, $a=2$ and $b=7$ is the strongest case, but we only have one direction of the implication)

Comment: @MiloBrandt If I'm not mistaken, your inequalities are in the wrong direction.  My interpretation of the problem is "Find all values $a$ and $b$ such that $0<x<5$ implies $a<x+2<b$".  Certainly, $x\in (0,5)$ implies that $x+2\in (-50,50)$ since $(0,5)+2=(2,7)\subseteq (-50,50)$.  $a=-50$ does not contradict anything, nor does $b=50$.  On the other hand, $x=2,a=5$ you would have $0<x=2<5$ but $5\not\lt x+2=4$

Comment: I'm going to quibble that the question was a simple if statement and not an equivalency if and only if statement.  No 0 < x < 5 iff 2  < x+2 < 7 and we and have a < x + 2 < 7 so a $\not > 2$ and $ b \not < 7$ but we can easily have a < 2 and b > 7.

Comment: @JMoravitz Oops, my mistake - yes, the inequalities should definitely go the other direction from how I wrote them.